# Error: "Select is not valid for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to view the table agents, but it keeps giving me an error.

```
select*from[agents];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this, SQL doesn't allow `[]` around the table name, either just call it explicitly or make a reference to `agents` table.

```
  SELECT * FROM agents;
```